# java replace list with sublist

Tags: java, list, replace

I have a list

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,3,4,2,4,5,3,10));
```

And I have another sublist

```
ArrayList sublist = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(4,5,3));
```

I was looking around for a functionality to replace 
the sublist inside list

with another sublist

```
ArrayList sublist = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(100,100)));
```

so after the find and replace , the new list should become :

```
list = (1,2,3,100,100,4,2,100,100,10);
```

I could not find any api for this one in java.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there exists any api for doing this or not, but what you could do is take advantage of the List interface in Java.

If you combine the use of 
containsAll(Collection c) 
          Returns true if this list contains all of the elements of the specified collection.

removeAll(Collection c) 
          Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation).

and

addAll(int index, Collection c) 
          Inserts all of the elements in the specified collection into this list at the specified position (optional operation).

I think you can easily accomplish what you need.

Take a look here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: This will just check/remove/add the individual elements of the handed over collection, but will not treat them as a coherent list. E.g. in the example found inside the question it would remove ALL 4s 5s and 3s.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the sublist as a *true* sublist of `list`, e.g. using [`List#subList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29), then (non-structural) changes made to `sublist` will be reflected in `list`.

```
List<Integer> list = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 3, 10);
List<Integer> sublist = list.subList(3, 6);

for (int i=0; i<sublist.size(); i++)
{
    sublist.set(i, 100);
}

System.out.println(sublist);
// prints 100, 100, 100
System.out.println(list);
// prints 1, 2, 3, 100, 100, 100, 4, 2, 4, 5, 3, 10
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/ljvd0

---

<sub>[`Lists.newArrayList(...)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList%28E...%29) comes from [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).</sub>